# R raster error [writeStart] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have 36 csv files with `lat`, `lon` and `value` for random points in the world.
Each file is quite big so it's not practical to merge them in a single file.

What I want to do is:

1. Create a blank raster covering the entire globe
2. Loop through each csv and fill the blank raster with the `value`
3. If a cell in blank raster is not present in csv, simply assign a value of 1 to it.

Here's my approach

```
library(terra)

# create a blank raster 
r <- terra::rast(ncols=129600, 
                 nrows=64800, 
                 xmin=-180, 
                 xmax=180, 
                 ymin=-90, 
                 ymax=90,
                 resolution = 0.002777778,
                 crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")


# get list of csv in folder 
file_list <- list.files(getwd())
 
# loop through each csv
for(f in seq_along(file_list)){
   
  file_ref <- file_list[f]
   
  temp <- read.csv(file_ref)
  v <- terra::vect(temp, geom = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") # convert csv to point
    
  terra::rasterize(x = v, y = r, field = "value", background = 1, 
                  filename = file.path(getwd(), 'mask.tif'),
                  overwrite = FALSE) 
  rm(temp, v)        
}
```

At the 10th iteration, I get the following error:

```
Error: [writeStart] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it
```

I am not able to understand the error and how to fix it?

Comment: You're looping over your csv files and write the output of `rasterize()` to disk using the same filename `mask.tif` each time. I would expect this to fail after the first iteration. What exactly is your goal? Do you want as many tifs as you had csv files or do you need an all-encompassing raster with data from all csv files?

Comment: My goal is the latter. An all encompassing raster with data from all csv files.

Comment: You answered one of my previous questions for a single file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159838/replace-values-in-raster-for-selected-cells/73162483#73162483 but now I want to do it for multiple csv files

Comment: Basically, I want to populate a blank raster with values from csv files except that the csv files are split into individual files. I hope this is clear.

Comment: How many objects per csv file are we talking about? I'd consider merging them into a single data.frame nevertheless, if possible. Otherwise you would need to merge 36 resulting raster from `rasterize()` into a single one after having processed all csv files.

Comment: Total size of the folder with csv is ~10.5 GB. So each file on average is around 291 MB. How would `rasterize()` work for individual 36 tiles if you don't mind me asking. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, unless you have at least 32 GB of RAM, I would not try this. Hmm.. I'd say this depends on your data if you can make use of `terra::merge()` to simply merge individual and not overlapping tiles or if you need further logic to aggregate values when merging overlapping raster data.

Comment: Yes if I create induvial tiles for each of the 36 csv and merge them together, I hope this works. Thank you for the pointers. I will try it.

Comment: P.S. I have 32 GB RAM but I don't think merging together all CSV and then doing is quite memory efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you don't want to keep the load in memory, seems like you have to write your data to disk. I really am no expert in this, but let's try. I want to know if this works.

First of all, I'd get rid of your static filename in `rasterize()`:

```r
library(terra)

# create a blank raster 
r <- rast(ncols = 129600, 
          nrows = 64800, 
          xmin = -180, 
          xmax = 180, 
          ymin = -90, 
          ymax = 90,
          resolution = 0.002777778,
          crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")


# get list of csv in folder 
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
 
# loop through each csv
for(f in seq_along(file_list)){
   
  # read csv 
  temp <- read.csv(file_list[f])

  # convert data.frame to SpatVect
  v <- vect(temp, geom = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 
  
  # burn values to raster and write tif to disk 
  rasterize(x = v, y = r, field = "value", background = 1, 
            filename = paste0("mask_", f, ".tif"),
            overwrite = FALSE)        
}
```

Now you should have 36 tif files written to disk. You can re-import them at once making use of `rast()`. What you get, is a `SpatRast` object with 36 layers:

```r
r_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif")

r_stack <- rast(r_list)

# the result should look approximately like this:

r_stack
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 64800, 129600, 36  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.002777778, 0.002777778(x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : p1_mask.tif  
#>               p2_mask.tif  
#>               p3_mask.tif  
#> names       :        lyr.1,        lyr.1,        lyr.1 
#> min values  : 0.0008870518, 0.0001774965, 0.0022119265 
#> max values  :            1,            1,            2
```

You can reduce the dimensions to 1 by e.g. making use of e.g. `min()` - `max()` and `mean()` would probably not make very much sense here if your values are < 1 as I learned in your other question and your background value is 1 - and write the result to disk:

```r
min(r_stack) |> writeRaster("full_mask.tif")
```

This should probably work quite well as long as `min()` suits your needs. If you need another aggregation function, you probably will have to get rid of `rasterize(..., background = 1)` and use `writeRaster(..., NAflag = 1)` instead. Eventually consider adjusting the `fun` argument in `rasterize()` also, because this is one of the main parts where aggregation is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the csv files first. If you cannot combine them all, you can perhaps do this in two steps. If there are duplicate locations (in terms of grid cells) something like the below may reduce the size of the dataset:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=129600, nrows=64800)
file_list <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".csv$")
 
v <- NULL
for (f in seq_along(file_list)){
    temp <- read.csv(file_list[f])[, c("lon", "lat", "value")]
    temp$cell <- cellFromXY(r, temp[, c("lon", "lat")])
    temp$lon <- temp$lat <- NULL
    v <- rbind(v, temp)
    # assuming fun=min
    v <- aggregate(v[,"value",drop=FALSE], v[,"cell",drop=FALSE], fun=min]
}
```

And then

```
v <- vect(xyFromCells(r, v$cell), atts=v[,"value", drop=FALSE])
rasterize(v, r, field="value", background=1, filename='mask.tif')
```

Comment: Thank. I am not able to understand the purpose of this line in the loop. `v <- aggregate(v[,"value",crop=FALSE], v[,"cell",drop=FALSE], fun=min]`. Is the `aggregate` function from `terra` since it doesn't seem like it takes crop=FALSE argument.

Comment: should have been `drop`